# playing a guess number game in python till the user opts to quit

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

play_game=input("Do you want to play ? Y/N :")
play_game=play_game.upper()
print(play_game)

while play_game == 'Y':
    #Type of game does the user wish to play
    game_type=input("please select a type:'H' for hard,'M' for medium ,'E' for easy  :")
    game_type=game_type.upper()

    #print(game_type)
    if game_type=='E':
        #generating a random number between 1 and 10
        random_number=random.randint(1,10)
        print(random_number)

        guess_times=0
        #guessing a number
        while guess_times<3:
            user_number=(input("Enter the number \n:"))
            user_number=int(user_number)
            guess_times+=1
            if user_number!=abs(user_number):
                print("the number should be a +ve number")
            else:
                if user_number==random_number:
                    print("Congratulaions,%d is the correct guess and you guessed in %d attempts"%(user_number,guess_times))
                    break
                if user_number<random_number:
                    print("the number,%d is lower than the guessed number"%user_number)
                if user_number>random_number:
                    print("the number,%d is higher than the guessed number"%user_number)
else:
        print("not the valid option")
print("bye")
```

I created a simple guess game above. It is working fine. But I want the user to play the game until the user decides to not to play.

I am using the while loop at the beginning of the game and once the user enters the game the option to quit is not being opted.

I do not want to use functions yet, as I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update `play_game` in your loop; you'll need to ask the user again at the end of the loop:

```
while play_game == 'Y':
    # your game 

    play_game = input("Do you want to play again? Y/N :").upper()
```

Then, by the time the loop goes back to the top, if the user did not enter `y` or `Y` at that prompt, the game ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an option for game_type, .e.g Q for quit:

```
game_type=input("please select a type:'H' for hard,'M' for medium ,'E' for easy , Q to quit :")
```

And change the end of the code like this:

```
elif game_type == 'Q':
    print("bye")
    break
else:
    print("not the valid option")
```